# JQuery not deleting correct row in view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My view currently looks like this:

```
<li class="list" data-id="<%=list.id%>">
  <div class="view" id="<%=list.id%>">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" checked="">
      <%= button_to "Delete", { action: "destroy", id: list.id }, method: :delete, :class => "destroy", remote: true %>
    <label><%= list.name %></label>
  </div>
  <%= form_for(list, remote: :true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "edit" %>
  <% end %>  
</li>
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.order("created_at DESC")
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      if request.xhr?
        @lists = List.all
        # somehow only send back the html for the page update
        render :layout => false
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @lists = List.all
      render :index
    end
  end

  def update
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    if @list.update(list_params)
      render
    else
      render 'list/show'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list = List.find_by(params[:id])
    @list.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lists_path }
      format.js #rails default: go to views/todos/destroy.js.erb
    end
  end

  private
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

and my current destroy.erb.js file looks like this:

```
var id = "<%= @list.id %>";

$("#" + id).slideUp();
```

It is working with AJAX, but it always deletes the bottom row first(as opposed to the id, clicked on)...How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to `slideUp()` the `<li ...>...</li>` or are you trying to `slideUp()` what inside the list item?  I'd try: `$("#" + id).parent().slideUp();`

Comment: When I call parent, the same thing happens.  I want the div with the Id of list.id to slide up.  Right now, no matter where I click, the last element on the page slides up.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with my index being  lists = List.order("created_at DESC").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this in your contoller:

```
def destroy
  list = List.find_by(params[:id])
  list.destroy
  @list_id = params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to lists_path }
    format.js #rails default: go to views/todos/destroy.js.erb
  end
end
```

Then in js:

```
var id = "<%= @list_id %>";
console.log(id);
$("#" + id).slideUp();
```

You're destroying the record, so I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you should be referencing properties of destroyed records. Also, check your console after you do it and make sure the id is what you're expecting.

Comment: the instance variable should still have the id so there's nothing wrong with his rails code.

Comment: This works!  do you have any idea, why @list.id wasn't working before?

Comment: @jvnill, thanks for the info, I would still consider it bad practice referencing an attribute of a record you've destroyed tho, no? @Becca, I'm not sure. You could revert back to the old code, but keep `console.log(id)` in there and see if you can find the problem that way. Also, I agree with the part of illusionist's answer about the instance variables and updated my answer accordingly. Could you accept it as correct?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure if it's considered a bad practice or not but I don't see any reason why it would be one.  In this particular scenario though, there's no need to use an instance variable since you can just use `params[:id]` in the view.  What's puzzling is that Becca's original code should've worked unless `@list.id` is being set to nil after destroy which would explain why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
def destroy
  # Its better to have local variable as you are not going to need any
  #   instance variable and minimal @instance variables should be use only if required. They are expensive actually
  list = List.find_by(params[:id])
  list.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to lists_path }
    format.js #rails default: go to views/todos/destroy.js.erb
  end
end
```

and in `views/todos/destroy.js.erb`

```
    console.log(id);
    // No need to save the id in any instance variable as params is available here as well
    $("#<%= h params[:id] %>").slideUp('slow', function(){
     // Better to delete the record from the DOM
     $(this).remove();
    });
```

> Note: You should never render `params` directly in the DOM, you should escape the string instead. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h